# FatalErrorException in routes.php line 113: Call to a member function delete() on null in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to delete a file through routes.php but it is generating the following error:

```
FatalErrorException in routes.php line 113: Call to a member function delete() on null
```

This is the view where the function is placed in the delete button.

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="row">
            @foreach($properties->files as $index=>$file)

                  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-2">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                      <img src="{{ URL::asset('uploads/products/' . $file->name) }}" alt="{{ $file->property_id }}" width="300" height="200">
                      <div class="caption">
                        <div class="caption" align="center">
                            <form action="{{ url('file/'.$file->id) }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                {{ csrf_field() }}
                                {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
                                <button onclick="return confirm('Está seguro eliminar esta imagen?')" class="button btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Eliminar imagen"><i class="material-icons delete-white">delete</i></button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>           

            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
```

And this is the path I'm using to delete the file in the directory and database.

```
// Delete files
    Route::delete('/file/{id}', function ($id) {
        //File::findOrFail($id)->delete();
        $file = File::find(Input::get('id')->delete());

        $filename= Input::get('upload');
        $path = 'uploads/products/' . $file->filename;

        //return redirect('/');
        return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Imagen eliminada satisfactoriamente!!!');

    });
```

Comment: What you have commented out is the correct answer... `File::findOrFail($id)->delete();` ... and are you trying to delete the file from the file system? Not sure what version of Laravel you are using, but this can help: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#deleting-files

Comment: Hey thanks @upful, it is correct, with File :: findOrFail ($ id) -> delete (); I can remove it from the DB, but what I am trying to do is remove the image I have stored in the directory so I am trying to get it named with $ filename = Input :: get ('upload'); But really in this part is that I am a little confused.

Comment: Which version of Laravel are you using? How is the file being uploaded?

Comment: Laravel version 5.2

Comment: Look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/filesystem for file handling, your question is too broad to cover in a single answer

Comment: You can see it here, from this question extend this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42659183/sqlstate23000-integrity-constraint-violation-1048-column-property-id-canno

Comment: Ok, let me review the documentation for this case, it is a confusion in how I delete a file in the directory where it is destined to be saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the recommendations, but I decided to change the method to handle these events.

1 - I create a new controller (FilesController) and through the controller I passed the parameters for elimination in the BD and the public path, for this controller we use the destroy method.

2 - I create a Route resource from the same controller.

This is the File model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class File extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'files';

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'property_id'];

    // Relation with Property
    public function property()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Property');
    }
}
```

This is the FilesController method:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\File;
use Redirect;
use Storage;

class FilesController extends Controller
{
    public function destroy(Request $request, $id)
    {

        $file = File::find($id);

        $fileName = $file->name;

        //dd($fileName);

        $file_path = public_path() . "/uploads/products/" . $fileName;

        //dd($file_path);

        if(File::exists($file_path))
        { 
            unlink($file_path);
        }

        $file->delete();

        return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Imagen eliminada satisfactoriamente!!!');

    }
}
```

The route:

```
Route::resource('properties','PropertyController');
```

And this is the part in the view that delete the files:

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="row">
            @foreach($properties->files as $index=>$file)

                  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-2">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                      <img src="{{ URL::asset('uploads/products/' . $file->name) }}" alt="{{ $file->property_id }}" width="300" height="200">
                      <div class="caption">
                        <div class="caption" align="center">
                            {!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE','route' => ['files.destroy', $file->id],'style'=>'display:inline']) !!}

                                {!! Form::hidden('_method', 'DELETE') !!}

                                {!! csrf_field() !!}

                                @permission('role-delete')
                                <button onclick="return confirm('Se eliminara la propiedad de la lista')" class="button btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Eliminar imagen" data-id="{{$file->id}}"><i class="material-icons delete-white">delete</i></button>
                                @endpermission

                            {!! Form::close() !!}
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>           

            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
```

With this simple form we can remove an image of the DB and the public path.

I hope to collaborate with other passionate people.

Answer (score 1):

When processing request input, there are two types of parameters: route parameters and query parameters. Route parameters are part of the url and are made available as parameters to the route handler (closure or controller method), whereas query parameters come from the query string and are made available through the request data (Input facade that you are using).

As written, your code has two issues. First, your file id is a route parameter, but you're trying to access it as if it were a query parameter. Second, you're actually attempting to call `delete()` on the id itself, which is actually `null` since it doesn't exist as a query parameter.

The line that you have commented out should work fine:

```
File::findOrFail($id)->delete();
```

---

It looks like you're also attempting to delete a file from the file system when you delete your `File` record. I would suggest you add a `deleted()` event to your `File` method, so that whenever a `File` model is deleted, it deletes the associated file from the file system.

```
class File extends Model
{
    public static function boot()
    {
        // make sure to call the parent boot
        parent::boot();

        // this function will be called whenever a File is deleted
        static::deleted(function ($model) {
            // delete the file when the model is deleted. very basic,
            // you'll want to add in more sanity checks, etc.

            // get the file path
            $path = 'uploads/products/' . $model->filename;

            // delete the file
            unlink($path);
        });
    }
}
```

You could also use the `deleting()` event, which will fire before the File record is deleted from the database. If you did this, you could return `false` from the event if the file fails to delete, and that will prevent the record from being deleted from the database.

Comment: Hey thanks @patricus, it is a confusion in how I delete a file in the directory where it is destined to be saved.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and I understand, but what happens is that I have data in a table and the associated log files in another table, so I was trying to delete the records of the files without affecting the records of the table where the data are Of the form.

If you can, look where this issue extends: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42659183/sqlstate23000-integrity-constraint-violation-1048-column-property-id-canno

Answer (score 1):

The error is generated because you are trying to retrieve a value from an input field which does not exist. You should read the documentation and see the difference between Input and Request [Requests & Input](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests)

Since there is no input field in your form and you are just passing and id in your form request, change this

```
 $file = File::find(Input::get('id'))->delete();
```

to this

```
 $file = File::find(Request::segment(2))->delete();
```

It should work fine now.

**Updated:**
Make sure you have your model class in your web route. Also make sure you're using Request `use Illuminate\Http\Request;`
In your web route use Request. Do the following: 
Change this

```
// Delete files
Route::delete('/file/{id}', function ($id) {
    //File::findOrFail($id)->delete();
    $file = File::find(Input::get('id')->delete());

    $filename= Input::get('upload');
    $path = 'uploads/products/' . $file->filename;

    //return redirect('/');
    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Imagen eliminada satisfactoriamente!!!');

});
```

to this

```
// Delete files
Route::delete('/file/{id}', use function (Request $request) {

    File::findOrFail($request->segment(2))->delete();

    $filename= Input::get('upload');
    $path = 'uploads/products/' . $file->filename;

    //return redirect('/');
    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Imagen eliminada satisfactoriamente!!!');

});
```

Comment: Hey thanks Carlos, This returns a syntax error FatalErrorException in routes.php line 114: syntax error, unexpected ')'